# Subdivide doesn't work on face after subdividing and smoothing vertex on another face of mesh

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

Trying to build simple monitor :D

[image: gif]

Comment: It does. But no edges can be created there to split the faces because the original face is Ngon. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71003/subdividing-a-face-with-subdivided-edges and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57534/cant-subdivide-face and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53130/subdivide-a-face-into-smaller-faces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mr Zak says above in comments, face with more than 4 verts often give troubles editing, like here. It is usually better to avoid ngons and stick to "quad" face (4 verts. 3 verts is also bad for animation).

But, if you wish, you could edit your mesh first to make the side face a quad face, using knife tool: in ortho side mode, use <kbd>K</kbd>, followed by <kbd>C</kbd> - to cut straight lines - and <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through all mesh.

Then click to start the cut,

[image]

click to end the cut

[image]

and press <kbd>enter</kbd> to confirm. You get this.

[image]

This allows you to to create a loop (since normal face loop tools won't work either, for the same reason as subdivide):

[image]

the side face is now a "quad" and subdivide works:

[image]